# Wordpress default theme cannot get full page on entry content div

Tags: pages, css

I am trying to create this very simple landing page on Wordpress using the basic theme but customizing my homepage. At first I tried through Visual Composer but then did so as well through the text classic editor directly in HTML, in both cases, my content is limited to a certain width of the page and I cannot get it to 100%. It would be great if I could get help in solving this and gegttig the content to use the full width of the page. Thank you for your help! My HTML code is as follows:

```
<div class="introrow">
<div class="introleft">TEXT
</div>
<div class="introright"><img src="..."></div>
</div>
```

My CSS is as follows:

```
.site-header, .site-footer, .entry-header {display:none!important;
}

h1:not(.site-title):before, h2:before { display:none!important;}

.introleft, .introright {
    width: 50%!important;
    float:left;
overflow:hidden;
}

.introrow {
    width:100%!important;
}
.introright img{
    margin:auto;
    display:block;
    width:100%!important;
    height:auto;
}

.entry-content {
    margin:0px!important;
    padding:0px!important;
    max-width:100%!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was a theme, issue, I just changed the theme to something more simple and it is now working. Hope this helps someone!